# ResourceDictionary in MergedDictionaries Source causing VS 2012 Designer not to load

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, resourcedictionary, visual-studio-designer, mergeddictionaries

the line ResourceDictionary Source="..." ist underlined and the VS designer throws an Exception. Everything was working in VS 2008

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MySolution.MyProject;component/Styles/MyStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Exception:

Exception:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item (Same for the InnerException)
at `Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateChildren(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, DocumentCompositeNode compositeNode, Boolean isNewInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

what is the "build Action" set for your MyStyles.xaml?

try setting this to "page" if it is not already set-up like this.

see this other answer for details: (it seems to me that this could be related in a way)

[Style TargetType causes XamlParseException when not attached to debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299664/style-targettype-causes-xamlparseexception-when-not-attached-to-debugger)