# How to Debug "Source Not Available" WPF error

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, stack-trace

I have a WPF application that has started failing with the following error at start:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'BorderBrush'.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
```

This is not very forthcoming about what has caused the error. I have tried turning on the CLR Exceptions and restarting as per [This Page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed220be1-aaf8-4cc5-9954-8387ee07bdc3/source-not-available-when-debugging?forum=vsdebug), but it did not give any more information; I turned on the disassembly, but don't understand what it means. Turning on  "Just My Code" debugging and all the Exception Settings as per [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629340/what-does-external-code-in-the-call-stack-mean) got slightly more in the exception stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message='{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'BorderBrush'.
Source=WindowsBase
StackTrace: at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, 
RequestFlags requests)

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.RequestFlags)
```

but none of this gives me (that I can see) any information about *what code* is failing. I have got down to deleting various bits and re-starting the app, but it is extremely time-consuming and I can't help but wonder - is there something else I should be doing.

Is there any way I can find out which bit of code is failing, or any clues (e.g. search terms to look for in my code, clues as to whether it would be a .xaml or a .cs page, places to look in the Exception details, anything) that might help narrow down the location? For instance, is this something that would only be returned by a failed attempt to override the template defaults in wpf, or might it be caused by one of my windows - Is it likely to have come from a style maybe?

Basically, other than seeing that there seems to be a place where I should be setting the `BorderBrush` and am not, I have no idea how to find what error I need to fix - and since it is a missing thing, I don't know how to find it. Any leads, hunches or advice will be greatly received!

This is a WPF Windows Application, writing in Visual Studio 2019 using .NET 4.8

Comment: this typically happens when wpf is trying to resolve a binding before the bounded dependency object is initialized. I would check for unset value inside all converters, callbacks or any other c# code that goes in the middle of wpf pipeline

Comment: Web searching for "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is not a valid value" might be a good tactic. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089272/dependencyproperty-unsetvalue-is-not-a-valid-value-for-property-focusvisual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there really is no way to find out clearly where the error was, but through a process of deleting files, clearing out references and reinstating, I was able to find the problem.

There was a reference to a static resource in a connected .DLL that no longer existing since the .DLL was republished without checking. The change in name there meant that a resource was not found and the unset value was sent to the Dependency Property. It would be lovely if Microsoft were able to provide some sort of check on the location of problematic resources.